# Remove duplicate rows which have values as that of column header

Tags: r, duplicates, rows, columnheader

My data somewhat looks like this:

```
    +--------+--------+--------+
| region |  name  | salary |
+--------+--------+--------+
| west   | raj    | 100    |
| north  | simran | 150    |
| region | name   | salary |
| east   | prem   | 250    |
| region | name   | salary |
| south  | preeti | 200    |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

The names of my column headers are being repeated in row no 3 and 5. How can I delete row no 3 and 5 using R and retain the column header as it is so that my output looks like this:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| region |  name  | salary |
+--------+--------+--------+
| west   | raj    |    100 |
| north  | simran |    150 |
| east   | prem   |    250 |
| south  | preeti |    200 |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Assuming that my original data has too many rows, I do not want to simply select row numbers and delete them using the command Data[-c(3, 5), ]

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example. But you problem is simple enough, just use grep or other such functions to id any rows that match the colnames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution

```
x <- data.frame(x =c("a", "b", "c", "x"), z = c("a", "b", "c", "z"))
## identify rows which match colnames 
matched <- apply(x,1, function(i) i[1] %in% colnames(x) && i[2] %in% colnames(x))

## Take the inverse of the match
x[!matched,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use str_detect() with filter to remove those rows.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
    region = c("west", "north", "region", "east","region","south"),
    name = c("raj", "simran","name","prem", "name","preeti"),
    salary = c("100","150","salary","250","salary","200")
)

df_2 <- df %>%
    filter(!str_detect(salary,"[Aa-zZ]"))

df_2
```

Or you can use base R

```
df_2 <- df[-grep("[Aa-zZ]",df$salary),]
df_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, `salary` is a numeric field, you can simply do this -

```
# assuming df is your dataframe

clean_df <- df[!is.na(as.numeric(df$salary)), ]
```